# How many ways can we arrange 7 books, including 2 math books and 1 physics book, with the math books next to each other and left of the physics book?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I have 7 books I want to arrange on a shelf. Two of them are math books, and one is a physics book. How many ways are there for me to arrange the books if I want to put the math books next to each other, and put both of them to the left of the physics book?

Comment: Update: I know that its 2!*4!, but I'm not sure how to count in the has to be on left thing.

Comment: Want to share how you get $2! \cdot 4!$?

Comment: There are 2 ways to arrange the math books, and 4! ways to arrange the normal books. Sorry, I should've explained.

Answer (score 5):

The answer you have seems to assume the math books must be next to the physics book, not just somewhere to the left of it.  It is still not right.  You want a block of math-math-physics and there are $2!$ ways to arrange these books into a block.  Counting the block as a book, you now have five books, so there are $5!$ ways to arrange the books, for a total of $2!\cdot 5!=240$ ways to arrange them.

If you don't require that the math books and physics book be next to each other, there are $2!$ ways to arrange the two math books into a pair.  There are then $6!$ ways to arrange the pair and the five other books.  Half of these have the math books somewhere to the left of the physics book, so there are $2!\cdot 6! \cdot \frac12=720$ ways to arrange the books now.

Comment: +1, clever to divide by 2 in the last case instead of specifying the cases

Comment: Yes, alculus gives the solution as 6!/2*2. Thanks for everyone's help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 math books, 1 physics book, and 4 other books.

First, glue the math books together.   There are $2!$ ways to do this.

Second, arrange the stuck-together math books, physic book, and 4 other books.   There are $(1+1+4)!$ ways to do this.

Third, realise that $1/2!$ of the above arrangements will have the physics book in the wrong side of the math books.   Eliminate them from the count.

Putting this together we have $2!\times 6! \big/ 2!$ ways to arrange the books on the shelf in the desired pattern.   That is $\boxed{720}$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
So you have math books $M$ and $m$ and a physics book $p$, with 4 other books. Each satisfying arrangement has $Mm$ or $mM$ and then the physics book.

1. Pick location of the physics book (cannot put it in position 1 or 2)
2. Depending on (1), pick location of math books (2 out of how many choices)? Will need to break into cases depending on (1).
3. Account for 2 orders of math books - $mM$ or $Mm$
4. Account for random order of other books.

What do you get?

Comment: If you put the physics book in position 3, you get 1 way, in position 4, 2 5 gives you 3, etc. So its 2!*4!*(1+2+3+4+5) = 720. Am I right?

Comment: @Thunder_Penguin yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

The arrangement of the physics and math books creates a "block". Because there are two math books, there are two ways to make the block. This block can anywhere between the left and right side of the shelf. Besides there's three books, there are four other books. By themselves, the four books can be arranged $4!$ different ways. However, we have to consider how many ways the block can be set up. It can be on the far left, it can have one book to its left, two books to its left, three books to its left or four books to its left. That makes a total of 5 orientations.

Thus, there are $2 \cdot 5\cdot 4!=240$ ways to arrange books.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for the save ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can arrange the books on the shelf, pretending that the two math books are actually one book because they must be next to each other. In exactly half of these arrangements, the math books will be to the left of the physics book, giving $\frac{6!}2=360$ arrangements.

However, in each of these arrangements, there are two ways to arrange the math books, so the total number of arrangements is $360\cdot 2=720$.